# calling Endpoints AsyncTask with JNI error

Tags: android, c++, google-app-engine, android-ndk, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm developing a multiplayer game for Android using Appengine as backend. Everything sets up well, then I generated endpoints code for Android, which also works really good.

Java class that execute an Endpoints class.

java code:

```
public static void saveData()
{
    new EndpointsTask().execute(mActivity.getApplicationContext());
}

public class EndpointsTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, Long> {
    protected Long doInBackground(Context... contexts) {
        Noteendpoint.Builder endpointBuilder = new Noteendpoint.Builder(
            AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
            new JacksonFactory(),
            new HttpRequestInitializer() {
                public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) { }
            });
        Noteendpoint endpoint = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(
            endpointBuilder).build();
        try {
            Note note = new Note().setDescription("Note Description");
            //String noteID = new Date().toString();
            String noteID = "lalala";
            note.setId(noteID);

            note.setEmailAddress("E-Mail Address");      
            Note result = endpoint.insertNote(note).execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Which then called from NDK NativeActivity c++ code:

```
void CCHelper::saveData()
{
    PluginJniMethodInfo minfo;

    if(PluginJniHelper::getStaticMethodInfo(minfo, "com/util/Helper",  "saveData", "()V"))
    {
        minfo.env->CallStaticVoidMethod(minfo.classID, minfo.methodID,NULL);
        minfo.env->DeleteLocalRef(minfo.classID);
    }
}
```

When I call it from C++ using Jni, I got error:

> 04-16 17:31:20.178: W/dalvikvm(28843): dvmFindClassByName rejecting 'com/util/Helper'
>   04-16 17:32:16.553: A/libc(28843): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1)

I'm using a NativeActivity based application (cocos2d-x).

Is there a solution for this? Is it possible to call Endpoints code from NativeActivity?

Answer (score 0):

So I changed my C++ implementation to call JNI using std::thread

```
std::thread t (&HelloWorld::ThreadFunction,this);
t.join();

void HelloWorld::ThreadFunction()
{
    CCHelper::saveData();
}
```

java code, I removed AsyncTask execution :

```
public static void saveData()
{
    Noteendpoint.Builder endpointBuilder = new Noteendpoint.Builder(
        AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
        new JacksonFactory(),
        new HttpRequestInitializer() {
            public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) { }
    });

    Noteendpoint endpoint = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(
        endpointBuilder).build();
    try {
        Note note = new Note().setDescription("Note Description");
        String noteID = new Date().toString();
        note.setId(noteID);

        note.setEmailAddress("E-Mail Address");      
        Note result = endpoint.insertNote(note).execute();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Inside PluginJniHelper::getStaticMethodInfo JNI code

```
...
if(!JAVAVM)
{
    LOGD("JavaVM is NULL");
    break;
}

if (JAVAVM->GetEnv((void**)env, JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK)
{
    LOGD("Failed to get the environment using GetEnv()");
    break;
}

if (JAVAVM->AttachCurrentThread(env, 0) < 0)
{
    LOGD("Failed to get the environment using AttachCurrentThread()");
    break;
}
...
```

I got error Failed to get the environment using GetEnv() which is the VM failed when calling GetEnv().

Is there something I'm missing here?